# Tiling a background in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 2d, lwjgl

I'm sure this is a relatively simple question, it's just one thing I've always had trouble wrapping my mind around.

I have a 512x512 background I'd like to tile "infinitely." I've searched around and can't seem to find a whole lot, so I figured I'd come here. Anyway, here it is:

[background http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5003139/hud/stars_far.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5003139/hud/stars_far.png)

So, there you have it. I have a ship sprite that can move anywhere on a 2D plane, and this is a top-down game. How would I render this background so that it covers every pixel of an arbitrarily sized window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GL_REPEAT texture clamping/wrapping mode, texture coordinates outside the range [0,1] will wrap around, repeating the texture. So you can draw a screen filling quad, but use larger texture coordinates. For example using the texture coordinates (0,0) to (10,10) will repeat the texture 10 times in each direction. Repeating mode is enabled for the currently bound 2D texture with

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the "camera" will follow the ship, so the background will be moving in the opposite direction.

Comment: Just draw the background with its own projection/modelview and adjust the texture coordinates according to the ships movement.